# Using $compile in a directive triggers AngularJS infinite digest error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Any thoughts on why this directive is triggering an infinite digest error?

http://jsfiddle.net/smithkl42/cwrgLd0L/13/

```
var App = angular.module('prettifyTest', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello, world!';
})

App.directive('prettify', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    var template;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (!template) {
                template = element.html();
            }
            scope.$watch(function () {
                var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
                element.html('');
                element.append(compiled);
                var html = element.html();
                var prettified = prettyPrintOne(html);
                element.html(prettified);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

It seems to be the very first line in the `scope.$watch()` function that's triggering the model update, as when I remove that line, it doesn't trigger the error.

```
var compiled = $compile(template)(scope);
```

I'm a little confused as to why that line is triggering another $digest - it doesn't seem to be updating anything directly in the `scope`.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, e.g., some other way to check to see if the key values in the scope have actually changed so I can recompile the template? (And is there a better way of grabbing the template?)

Comment: What are you trying to `$watch`?

Comment: You cant compile the element directly like that. You can compile something and append it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `scope.$watch()` with just a function and no watch expression, it registers a watcher that gets triggered on every digest cycle. Since you're calling `$compile` within that watcher, that's effectively triggering another digest cycle each time since it needs to process the watchers created by your template. This effectively creates your infinite digest cycle.

To use the same code, you should probably just be compiling once in your postLink function, but I don't think you even need to do that - you should be able just use the `template` property. Then your `$watch()` statement should include an expression targeting the property you want to watch for changes - in this case, just `'message'`, and update the HTML accordingly.

Comment: The idea that Angular needs to process the watchers created by the template makes sense. The problem is that I'm trying to create a general-purpose directive that doesn't depend on knowing which specific model properties to watch. Here's my latest iteration, where I try to specify a target to watch, but the `$watch` doesn't seem to be getting triggered: http://jsfiddle.net/smithkl42/cwrgLd0L/16/

Comment: OK, got a little further. I figured out that because I was (now) using an isolated scope, I couldn't watch values in the parent scope. This works better: http://jsfiddle.net/smithkl42/cwrgLd0L/21/. But it's only updating to the *previous* value - somehow the template function is reading the old value out of the scope, not the new one. Still looking...

Comment: FWIW, I've created a second question for the next issue I'm running into :-). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511269/template-always-compiles-with-old-scope-value-in-directive